# finding square $k$ such that $k\mid 2^{k-1} -1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can we find a positive **square integer** $k>1$, which satisfies $k\mid 2^{k-1} -1$ ?
If yes, what are such $k>1$ values? Here $k = n^2$ and $n$ is some positive integer. If we cannot find such square integer $k>1$, then how to disprove the statement $k\mid 2^{k-1} -1$?

High regards and advanced thanks!

Richard Sieman

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into difficulty?  What tools do you have? The more you tell us, the better the answers will be. Cheers!

Comment: You couldn't even bother figuring out that $k=1$ is one of the solutions (which yields that we cannot 'disprove the statement').

Comment: @mathh! you are correct and I re-edited.

Comment: @mathtew conroy! If I given some other number in place of 2, it is workable by trail and error examples. However, if base is 2, I am unable to get.

Comment: $2^{n^2-1} - 1 = 2^{(n-1)(n+1)}-1 = (2^{n-1}-1)(1+2^{n-1}+2^{2(n-1)}+2^{3(n-1)}+ \cdots+2^{n(n-1)})$.  Whether $n^2$ divides that is the question.

Comment: $1093^2$ and $3511^2$ are two solutions. You may want to look up Wieferich primes. As of today, these are the only Wieferich primes that have been found. (Note that for squares of primes it is equivalent to ask wether $p^2$ divides $2^{p-1}-1$, because the exponent $p+1$ doesn't influence the $p$-adic valuation.) I just want to make clear that solutions may be very big.

Comment: @barto! Please could your make clear those solutions please. Importantly, I want to know how you got those two solutions?

Comment: They are known to be Wieferich primes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime.

Comment: @barto! I need some explanation. I have seen wiki. But, I could not get, how you got such two solutions. Is there any online calculator to find? if yes, please let me know.

Comment: I didn't find them. They are written on the wikipedia page: "As of October 2013, the only known Wieferich primes are 1093 and 3511."

Comment: @AGiftbox!Can you explain how 2^{n^2-1}= 1^{n+1} and how it is equal to 0 (mod n)?

Comment: @barto! can you prove my statement?

Comment: Which statement? It is true that there exist positive integers $n$ for which $n^2\mid2^{n^2-1}-1$, for example, n=1, 1093, 5311. The statement $n^2\mid2^{n^2-1}-1$ is sometimes true, but certainly not always. (For example $2^2\nmid2^{2^2-1}-1$ and $3^2\nmid2^{3^2-1}-1$). These three solutions (1, 1093, 5311) are the only known. If the abc-conjecture is true, there would be infinitely many prime numbers $n$ for which it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $n^2|(2^{n^2-1}-1)$.
Now it is obvious that $(2^r-1)|(2^{n^2-1}-1)$, where $r|(n^2-1)$, hence, 
$2^r-1=n^2$ for some positive integer $r$. Now $r$ cannot be even, (otherwise, $2^{2k}-n^2=1$ for $r=2k$, and factorising yield $2^k-n=1$ and $2^k+n=1$ for which $n=0$, or $2^k-n=-1$ and $2^k+n=-1$ for which $n=1$) so let $r=2k+1$, hence, $2^r-1=n^2$ becomes; $2^{2k+1}-1=n^2$ or 
$n^2-2(2^k)^2=-1$ which is Pell's equation for which all solutions are given by; $n+(2^k){\sqrt2}  \equiv (1+{\sqrt2})^{2t+1}$ for all non-negative integers $t$, $r=(2k+1)|(n^2-1)$, and can be used to narrow your search

Comment: It is true that _if_ $r\mid n^2-1$, then $2^r-1\mid 2^{n^2-1}-1$. However we cannot conclude that every divisor of $2^{n^2-1}-1$ is of the form $2^r-1$. (That isn't even true.) Besides, $2^r-1=n^2$ is only possible for $r=0,1$ because no square is $-1$ modulo $4$. No need of Pell's equation there.

Comment: Tanx for the obsevation